# Adding a light fixture to an existing fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I added a new light fixture by splicing into an existing fixture.   When I turn the light on, the existing light comes on, when I turn it off, the new light comes on.  What have I done wrong?  I want them both to turn on together.

Comment: Almost impossible to say what you did wrong without a more complete description of what you did. What cables and wires did you find coming into the existing switch and light? Photos or a drawing is always best, but a very complete description may serve as well.

Comment: Does this circuit involve any 3-way switches?  Do the 3-way messengers go through the fixture junction box?

Comment: I have no idea what I did wrong, but I took it apart and redid the whole thing and it works!  Go figure.  Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The method for adding a new light fixture to come on when the old one does is this: You do not disconnect any of the existing wires (except temporarily while working on it). You add wires only, connecting one screw on the old fixture to one screw on the new fixture, and the other screw on the old fixture to the other screw on the new fixture. This is called connecting the fixtures in parallel. Any method that does not connect the fixtures in parallel will not work.

Now -- exactly *how* you connect these screws together depends on what your fixtures look like, where power is supplied to the old light circuit (at the fixture or at the switch), and where (in what country and state) you live.

I strongly recommend that you continue to communicate on this site until you have a complete answer to your question, before doing any more work on your electrics. Judging by the mistake you describe, if you continue without guidance you may do much worse than make something that doesn't work properly. You may hurt yourself or damage your residence.

Answer (score 0):

If you took the black wire from the existing light to the black in the new fixture the white to white And ground to ground you may not have the wires stripped back far enough for the wire nuts to make a connection. This or a bad lamp. My current apprentice has done this several times and gets upset but the wires must be in contact and have enough compression for the wire nut to do its job.

Comment: That explanation covers the new light not working, it doesn't cover the new light coming on when the old one is off.